# Где лежит стандартная иконка "Сделать фото"?

Tags: java, android

Приложение работает с камерой.

Хочу в приложении использовать стандартную кнопку `Сделать фото`, и вот что подумал, ведь стандартная камера использует эту кнопку, значит она должна где то лежать... Возможно даже, что на всех устройствах она лежит в одном и том же месте...

Можно ли к ней добраться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фреймворк Android содержит множество иконок и получить их в своем проекте можно довольно легко. Например, иконка камеры:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />
```

то есть для доступа к системному ресурсу используется аннотация `@android:drawable`

В Android Studio вы можете визуально оценить и выбрать все доступные системные иконки через визуальный редактор, кликнув на три точки в любом атрибуте, которому требуется ресурс типа `Drawable` и выбрав раздел *android*:

[image: scrn]

Все же в приложении, которое не является частью системы, рекомендуется использовать собственные ресурсы, в том числе и иконки. Это гарантирует ожидаемый внешний вид на любой версии ОС, ведь сейчас актуальны как минимум два набора иконок: интерфейс Holo и интерфейс Material. Может случится так, что при очередном изменении дизайна системы, иконка будет изменена и никак не будет вписываться в ваш дизайн, смотреться чужеродным пятном, а то и изменено ее имя или она будет удалена вовсе.   Придется вносить изменения, искать замену и скорее всего использовать собственный ресурс.

Никто не может вам гарантировать, что какая-то системная иконка будет сохранять свой внешний вид, свое имя или вовсе существовать от версии системы к версии, соответственно это может стать проблемой для вашего приложения и использовать системные иконки в пользовательских программах крайне не рекомендуется.

Получить огромное количество иконок для своего проекта в модном сейчас Material-стиле непосредственно от Google вы можете [здесь](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons)

PS: приложение Камера использует собственные иконки, которые находятся внутри ее собственного apk, хотя и является системным приложением. Уже это говорит о том, что иконки самого фреймворка, только для системы, а не для приложений

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса скриншот. Мне стало интересно посмотреть следую вашему ответу какие есть иконки если нажать на три точки, но у меня почему то совсем другое меню открывается, может я не туда нажал? А вообще за ответ спасибо!

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Нажмите на вкладку System-откроется доступ к ресурсам системы. У меня Студия версии 2.1 и обновление по ветке canary (бета версии), там интерфейс уже поменялся немного. Раньше да, как у вас на скриншоте интерфейс был, но я не стал делать даунгрейд IDE, чтобы сделать такой же :)